# How to individually customise tick marks and labels in histogram

Tags: pgfplots, labels, axis, ticks, histogram

I need to mark three x values in a histogram. I thought a way would be introducing `extra x ticks` and customising `major tick length` and thickness so they show up more conspicuously. Is it possible to assign different length and thickness to each of them, and if so can I get some help with that?

Additionally, I would like each tick label to he different. When I introduce `xticklabel` if allocates the same label to all the extra ticks. How can I give each extra x tick a different label?

this is my code so far:

```
\documentclass[border=0.2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{ compat=1.9, every axis/.style={axis on top}}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[ybar,
    width=7.5cm,
    ymax=10,
    xmax=3,    
    xticklabel style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    yticklabel style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    xtick pos=left,
    ytick pos=left,
    extra x ticks = {1.10,1.38,1.62},
    extra x tick style={
    xticklabel={\footnotesize SC},
    xticklabel style={above, rotate=45,ultra thick,yshift=65, xshift=75},
    tick align=inside,
    major tick length=95},      
    every axis label = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    xlabel={xxxx},
    ylabel={yyyy},
    legend style = {anchor=north east, 
                   nodes={scale=0.75,transform shape},
                   font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},    
    enlarge y limits=-0.5,
    ]             
    \addplot+[hist={data=x,bins=9,data max=2,data min=-2.6},black!30, fill=black!30]
            table [y expr=1] {

2
0.5
2
-1.2
-0.3
-2
-1.55
0.2
-0.1
-1.4
1.1
-2
-2
-1
-2
0.5
1.7
2
0.33
-2
0.22
-2
-1
-1
0.2
1
2
-1
1.1
2
-1.3
-1.22
-2
0.33
0.22
1
0.1          
            };
            \addlegendimage{empty legend},
\addlegendentry{aaaa},
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This would be what I would like to achieve:

[image]

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just add them "by hand", i.e. using a loop.

```
\documentclass[border=0.2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{ compat=1.9, every axis/.style={axis on top}}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{axis}[ybar,
    width=7.5cm,
    ymax=10,
    xmax=3,    
    xticklabel style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    yticklabel style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    xtick pos=left,
    ytick pos=left,
    every axis label = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    xlabel={xxxx},
    ylabel={yyyy},
    legend style = {anchor=north east, 
                   nodes={scale=0.75,transform shape},
                   font=\sansmath\sffamily},
    label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},    
    enlarge y limits=-0.5,
    ]             
    \addplot+[hist={data=x,bins=9,data max=2,data min=-2.6},black!30, fill=black!30]
            table [y expr=1] {

2
0.5
2
-1.2
-0.3
-2
-1.55
0.2
-0.1
-1.4
1.1
-2
-2
-1
-2
0.5
1.7
2
0.33
-2
0.22
-2
-1
-1
0.2
1
2
-1
1.1
2
-1.3
-1.22
-2
0.33
0.22
1
0.1          
            };
            \addlegendimage{empty legend},
\addlegendentry{aaaa},
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {1.10,1.38,1.62}
{\edef\temp{\noexpand\draw[ultra thick] (axis cs:\X,0) -- (axis cs:\X,8.8-\Y) node[anchor=south
west,xshift=-2ex,font=\noexpand\sffamily]{label \Y} ;}
\temp} % axis cs: is not needed for pgfplots compat=1.11 or higher
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As always, perfect answers. Thank you so much!